# Which files in WordPress do I add API calls?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, api

I am trying to display templates from Duda on my WordPress website via Duda's API.

I have the code to:

- GET templates
- Output templates on-page and
- Allow a user to select a template

but I am unsure which files to add them to in WordPress.

My assumption is that GET templates will go in functions.php, template output will go in a custom page template (e.g templates.php) and I am unsure on the other.

The code is as follows:

**GET Templates:**

```
<?php
  define("API_USER","xxxxxxxxx");
  define("API_PASS","yyyyyyyyy");

  $templatesData = json_decode(getAllTemplates());

function getAllTemplates() {

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.duda.co/api/sites/multiscreen/templates');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, API_USER.':'.API_PASS);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
//execute cURL call
$output = curl_exec($ch);

//check result for correct HTTP code
if(curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) == 200) {
    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
} else {
    curl_close($ch);
    http_response_code(400);
    die('Error getting templates details: '. $output . '<br/>');
}
}
```

**Output pages:**

```
<?php
$templatesData = json_decode(getAllTemplates());

echo '<div class="row">';
//loop through each item of the template data and display in a card style layout
foreach($templatesData as $template) {
echo '<div class="col s12 m6 l4">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-image">
      <img class="materialboxed" src="' . $template->thumbnail_url . '">
      <a class="btn-floating tooltipped halfway-fab waves-effect waves-light red start-building" data-tooltip="Start editing this template" data-template-id="' . $template->template_id . '"><i class="material-icons">mode_edit</i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="card-content">
      <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4 truncate">' . $template->template_name . '</span>
      <a href="' . $template->preview_url . '" data-template-id="' . $template->template_id . '">Preview Template</a>
    </div>
    <div class="card-action">
      <a data-template-id="' . $template->template_id . '" href="#" class="start-building">Start with this template</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>';

}
echo '</div>';
```

**Allow users to select a template:**

```
<?php
define("API_USER","xxxxxxxxx");
define("API_PASS","yyyyyyyyy");

include_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/d-functions.php');

//check if post request contains template ID
if (isset($_POST["template_id"])) {

//create site
$siteName = createSite($_POST["template_id"]);

//create account with tmp info
$date = new DateTime();
$tempAcctName = 'tmp_' . uniqid() . '_' . $date->getTimestamp();
$account = createCustomerAccount($tempAcctName);

//grant access
grantAccountAccess($account,$siteName);

//generate & print sso link
echo getSSOLink($account,$siteName,'EDITOR');

//prevent rest of page from loading and kill other php commands
die();
}
?>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
  <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--Import materialize.css-->
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" 
  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.2/css/materialize.min.css"  
  media="screen,projection"/>

  <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="row top" style="background:#f1f1f1">
        <div class="col s12 center-align">
            <h4 class="">Choose a template to start from</h4>
            <p>Each template is natively responsive and can be fully customized to your 
     liking.</p>
         </div>
      </div>
  <div class="container">

  <?php

    $templatesData = json_decode(getAllTemplates());

    echo '<div class="row">';
    //loop through each item of the template data and display in a card style layout
    foreach($templatesData as $template) {
    echo '<div class="col s12 m6 l4">
     <div class="card">
    <div class="card-image">
      <img class="materialboxed" src="' . $template->thumbnail_url . '">
      <a class="btn-floating tooltipped halfway-fab waves-effect waves-light red start- 
   building" data-tooltip="Start editing this template" data-template-id="' . $template- 
   >template_id . '"><i class="material-icons">mode_edit</i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="card-content">
      <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4 truncate">' . $template->template_name 
  . '</span>
      <a href="' . $template->preview_url . '" data-template-id="' . $template->template_id 
  . '">Preview Template</a>
    </div>
    <div class="card-action">
      <a data-template-id="' . $template->template_id . '" href="#" class="start- 
  building">Start with this template</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>';

  }
  echo '</div>';

  ?>

  </div>
  <!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <script> $(document).ready(function(){$('.materialboxed').materialbox();});
    function createWebsite(tmpID) {
        var request = jQuery.ajax({
            url:window.location.pathname,
            beforeSend:function() {
              //display click notification while AJAX call is in progress
              Materialize.toast('Creating your website now..', 10000) 
            },
            method:"POST",
            data:{"template_id":tmpID}
        });

    request.success(function(d){
        var respData = d;
        console.log(respData);
        //display success message
        Materialize.toast('Successfully created website',10000);
        Materialize.toast('Sending you to edit..', 500,'', function(){ window.location = respData;
            })
    });

    //handle falures to create
    request.fail(function(d,sts,err){
        Materialize.toast('Website creation failed: ' + d, 5000)
        });
    }
    //find each start building links (both pencils and links) and call createwebsite function with template ID
    $('.start-building').each(function(e) {
        $(this).on('click',function(tmpID){
            var tmpID = $(this).data('template-id');
            createWebsite(tmpID);

        })
    })
  </script>
</body>
```